# Why does data stored in registers have memory addresses?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, assembly

If I have the following code:

```
-(int)number {
    int i = 3;
    return i;
}
```

I can get the memory address of the integer i, by doing &i. (say while paused on a breakpoint on the return line)

However the corresponding assembly (ARM) will simple be:

```
MOV R0, #3
```

Nowhere is the memory needed (except to store the instruction), so how can `i` have a memory address?

Comment: Curious. What is the address? Is it a valid address in the context of the program? Also, does the debugger show you the disassembly or was that obtained through a separate tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code might not need to use memory, but that does not mean it doesn't use memory. The compiler can implement it however it wants. Without optimization, this means variables will probably all be stored in memory, whether they need to be or not. For example, consider this very basic program:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    return i;
}
```

With optimization disabled (which it is by default), Apple clang 4.0 gives me the following assembly:

```
_main:
    sub   sp, sp, #4
    movw  r0, #0
    str   r0, [sp]
    add   sp, sp, #4
    bx    lr
```

With optimization enabled, I get a much simpler program:

```
_main:
    mov   r0, #0
    bx    lr
```

As you can see, the unoptimized version stores the 0 in memory, but the optimized version doesn't. If you were to use the optimized version in the debugger, it would fail to give you the address of `i`. I actually got an error that `i` was undefined, since it had been optimized out completely.